# Conditional resample to get the monthly average

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

i have a df with 4 columns and roughly 2000 rows.

the first 2 columns are the deciles on month 0 and deciles on month12 and the 3rd one is the value and 4th is the date.

what i want to capture is the average monthly mean
for example if Column 1 = 1 and column = 2 then get that months average value for all of the stocks with same deciles.
but unfortunately i'm getting blanks

My Code

```
for i in Labels=list(range(1,11):       
      for j in Labels=list(range(1,11):     
            dec2=dec2.loc[(dec2[decileT0]==i)&(dec2[decileT12]==j)]    
            dec2.value.resample('M', on='DATEID').mean()
```

Data sample

```
decileT0    decileT12   value        DATEID
6              6    -0.097774341    31/03/2006
4              5    -0.096971416    28/02/2006
1              2    -0.096923155    31/07/2006
6              6    -0.096895966    30/09/2007
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is the problem, but you are missing some brackets in your code. Does it even compile?

I put the brackets below:

```
for i in Labels=list(range(1,11)):       
      for j in Labels=list(range(1,11)):     
            dec2=dec2.loc[ ( dec2[decileT0] == i ) & ( dec2[decileT12] == j ) ]    
            dec2.value.resample('M', on='DATEID').mean()
```

Comment: Thanks victor, sorry yes i missed it out copying the code but that wasn't the issue unfortunately

Comment: When I try to compile your code I get compilations errors. Are you sure it is compiling? I have never seen a for loop in python like that.

Answer (score 0):

sorry victor i didn't really run the simplified before posting, the range was in a function so something like this i have run it i get the same error with the complete code.

```
Labels = list(range(1,11))
for i in Labels:       
      for j in Labels:     
            dec3=dec2.loc[(dec2['decileT0']==i)&(dec2['decileT12']==j)]    
            dec3.value.resample('M', on='DATEID').mean()
```

Comment: fix it i had to rename the new list to dec3 as i was altering the source series